# Vb.net equivalent of C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, equivalence

What is the equivalent vb.net code of the corresponding MouseDown event shown below (C#)? How should I implement this event in vb.net?

Thank you in advance, Goicox

```
var model = new PlotModel("MouseDown HitTestResult", "Reports the index of the nearest point.");

var s1 = new LineSeries();
s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
model.Series.Add(s1);
s1.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                model.Subtitle = "Index of nearest point in LineSeries: " + Math.Round(e.HitTestResult.Index);
                model.InvalidatePlot(false);
            };
```

Comment: The title is funny.

Comment: Use redgate reflector for converting code from CLR languages to VB/C#/C++ and vice versa. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: The event is defined in .NET code, which both C# and VB are built on top of.  The event will exist for the same class in VB with the same name.

Comment: @Servy: He's actually asking how to do lambdas.

Comment: @SLaks Perhaps that's what he meant; it's not what he asked.

Comment: Depending on your version, it may be necessary to have a separate method (instead of a lambda/anon method).  It can be helpful to declare "model" as WithEvents so you can get the correct signature stub handler for the event.  Then remove WithEvents and the "Handles" clause at the end, and use AddHandler to wire up the event.

Answer (score 1):

Simple convertion should do it :

```
Dim model = New PlotModel("MouseDown HitTestResult", "Reports the index of the nearest point.")

Dim s1 = New LineSeries()
s1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(0, 10))
s1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(10, 40))
s1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(40, 20))
s1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(60, 30))
model.Series.Add(s1)
s1.MouseDown += Function(s, e) 
model.Subtitle = "Index of nearest point in LineSeries: " &         Math.Round(e.HitTestResult.Index)
model.InvalidatePlot(False)

End Function
```

Sources : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Using this, I got the following error: Error 1 'Public Event MouseDown(sender As Object, e As OxyPlot.OxyMouseEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Comment: Actually I got the following which is working: AddHandler s1.MouseDown, AddressOf Me.LSMouseDown

Comment: Thats because you cannot convert that statement. You need to use the Addhandler statement and wire that event to a sub routine you make. Like Idle_Mind stated.

Comment: Well congratz , remember to mark helpfull posts aswell + rep is nice for everyone

Comment: Now a second question, how could I pass arguments to the delegate function in vb.net? In C# the MouseDown method is able to modify "model" variables (e.g. model.Subtitle). Goicox

Comment: also im thinking this is not exactly what you want, could you refresh you code up top and i can help you out further

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a VB 'Sub' lambda (available in VS 2010 and beyond):

```
AddHandler s1.MouseDown, Sub(s, e)
    model.Subtitle = "Index of nearest point in LineSeries: " & Math.Round(e.HitTestResult.Index)
    model.InvalidatePlot(False)
    End Sub
```